# Serve audio files with Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, audio, spring-boot

Is there a more efficient way of serving audio files with SpringBoot?

```
@RequestMapping(value = '/getSong/{id}', method = RequestMethod.GET)
def getMusic(HttpServletResponse response, @PathVariable Integer id) throws Exception {
    Music m = shuffler.findTrackPathById(id)
    if (m == null) {
        return "File not found"
    }
    response.setContentType("audio/mpg")
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "inline; filename=" + m.getFilename())
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(m.getFullpath())
    FileCopyUtils.copy(is, response.getOutputStream())
    response.getOutputStream().close()
}
```

I am experiencing this error every once in a while:

```
2016-06-26 08:47:16.460  INFO 10831 --- [      Thread-11] o.e.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler  : Stopped o.s.b.c.e.j.JettyEmbeddedWebAppContext@ea9e141{/,file:/private/var/folders/73/gwl8bs6s4hgcl6vyln6_wzsc0000gn/T/jetty-docbase.7966202443679651433.8080/,UNAVAILABLE} 
2016-06-26 08:47:46.463  WARN 10831 --- [      Thread-11] o.e.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool   : qtp1041326823{STOPPING,8<=8<=200,i=0,q=1} Couldn't stop Thread[qtp1041326823-19,5,main]
```

The HTTP request made from an Angular app doesn't download the file instantly (the speed is ~200Kb/s) - even though I am testing on my local machine. If I use curl or download it from the address bar, however, - it does get downloaded instantly.

Comment: The last paragraph pretty much proves that it's a client-side problem, yet you seem to assume it's a server-side problem?

Comment: yeah, when I terminate the server - I can see the ``Couldn't stop Thread`` warning. I can see in the Activity monitor that one java process is hanging, which I have to kill manually.

Comment: @kryger I am using ngAudio on the frontend and it works just fine http://danielstern.github.io/ngAudio/#/docs -- so this might cause the slow loading. But why does Spring throw the ``Couldn't stop Thread`` then? I think it's a server-side problem anyway. One thing I might have overlooked, what if the client disconnects before the server has served the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that I am serving audio files in the same thread as other resources (GET, POST).